# Razor Pages ajax post error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, post, antiforgerytoken

I'm building an AspNet Core Razor Pages Web site and I'm unable to execute a JQuery AJAX POST call to the server.
Here the server side code:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostUpdateQRCodeAsync(int id, string name, string description)
    {
        ...
    }
```

And here my ajax client side code:

```
function UpdateQRCodeData(id, name, description) {
  var url = "?handler=UpdateQRCode";
  var token = getToken();
  debugger
  return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + url,
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": token },
        data: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            description: description
        },
        contentType: "application/json;",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
  });
}
```

The getToken() function gets Antiforgery token from page.

The error I receive is the following:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing where it's wrong because you didn't describe it clearly. This message looks like a client-side error message? where is it reported?

Comment: Seems you're getting some server errors. Your anti-forgery token is proper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

cshtml(When use `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`,html will have a hidden input `__RequestVerificationToken`):

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<button onclick="UpdateQRCodeData(1,'name','description')">Ajax</button>
```

js(Parameters of handler OnPostUpdateQRCodeAsync is not get from body,so I remove `contentType: "application/json;",`):

```
<script>
    function UpdateQRCodeData(id, name, description) {
        var url = "?handler=UpdateQRCode";
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: {
                id: id,
                name: name,
                description: description
            },
            //contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostUpdateQRCodeAsync(int id, string name, string description)
        {
            return new JsonResult(new object { });
        }
```

result:
[image]